# multiple streams as different file descriptors in c

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I have a program where i need to supply 2 different streams as input.

If I only needed one stream as input, I could use stdin  like so

```
./a.out <file1
fgets(buf,1000,stdin)
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
./a.out --file1 <(cat file1) --file2 <(cat file2)
FILE *fp1 = fdopen(3,"r");
FILE *fp2 = fdopen(4,"r");
fgets(buf,1000,fp1);
fgets(buf,1000,fp2);
```

where I'm assuming that the streams I create with '<(cat file1)' and '<(cat file2)' will have file descriptor number 3 and 4.

Comment: You can use named pipes for this.  Or temporary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using bash as your shell, you can do the following:

```
./a.out 3< file1 4< file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run your program like this:

```
./a.out file1 file2
```

and use those files in your program like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    fgets(buf1, length_of_buf1, fp1);
    fgets(buf2, length_of_buf2, fp2);
```